# Group array of objects by multiple keys using d3.groups

Tags: arrays, d3.js, grouping

I've this dataset:

```js
const data = [ 
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mu', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: -1},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'muji', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 0},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mine', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 1},
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 1}, 
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido2', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: 1}, 
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido3', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 0}, 
  {animal: 'hamster', name: 'gerry', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0}, 
  {animal: 't-rex', name: 'dino', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: 0},
  {animal: 't-rex', name: 'sauro', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0},
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 's', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0}, 
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 'sss', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: -1}, 
]
```

And I want to group it by `animal` and by `status` to obtain something like:

```js
const grouped = {
  cat: {
    -1: [{animal: 'cat', name: 'mu', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: -1}],
    0: [{animal: 'cat', name: 'muji', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 0}]
    1: [{animal: 'cat', name: 'mine', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 1}]
  },
  dog: {
    0: [{animal: 'dog', name: 'fido3', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 0}],
    1: [
      {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 1}, 
    {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido2', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: 1}
    ]
  },
  hamster: {
    0: [{animal: 'hamster', name: 'gerry', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0}],
  },
  't-rex': {
    0: [{animal: 't-rex', name: 'dino', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: 0},
  {animal: 't-rex', name: 'sauro', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0},],
  },
  sheep: {
    -1: [{animal: 'sheep', name: 'sss', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: -1}],
    0: [{animal: 'sheep', name: 's', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0}],
  }
}
```

I used [`d3.groups`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#groups) to groups data:

```js
const grouped = d3.groups(data, d => d.animal, d => d.status)
/*
[
  [
    'cat',
    [
      [
        -1,
        [
          {
            animal: 'cat',
            name: 'mu',
            date: 2019-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
            status: -1
          }
        ]
      ],
      [
        0,
        [
          {
            animal: 'cat',
            name: 'muji',
            date: 2020-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
            status: 0
          }
        ]
      ],
      [
        1,
        [
          {
            animal: 'cat',
            name: 'mine',
            date: 2020-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
            status: 1
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    'dog',
    [
      [
        1,
        [
          {
            animal: 'dog',
            name: 'fido',
            date: 2020-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
            status: 1
          },
          {
            animal: 'dog',
            name: 'fido2',
            date: 2019-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
            status: 1
          }
        ]
      ],
      [
        0,
        [
          {
            animal: 'dog',
            name: 'fido3',
            date: 2020-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
            status: 0
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    'hamster',
    [
      [
        0,
        [
          {
            animal: 'hamster',
            name: 'gerry',
            date: 2018-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
            status: 0
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    't-rex',
    [
      [
        0,
        [
          {
            animal: 't-rex',
            name: 'dino',
            date: 2019-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
            status: 0
          },
          {
            animal: 't-rex',
            name: 'sauro',
            date: 2018-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
            status: 0
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    'sheep',
    [
      [
        0,
        [
          {
            animal: 'sheep',
            name: 's',
            date: 2018-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
            status: 0
          }
        ]
      ],
      [
        -1,
        [
          {
            animal: 'sheep',
            name: 'sss',
            date: 2018-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
            status: -1
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
*/
```

the grouping is working but data is not in the format I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain a `.reduce` after `d3.groups` in order that the nested array is recast into a nested object.

You can initialize the `reduce` with `{}` so it returns an object. `curr[0]` for each array returned from `d3.groups` will be the `animal`. `curr[1]` for each array returned from `d3.groups` will be the array of the `status` and the original array of items grouped per the `animal`/ `status` logic.

See below:

```js
const data = [ 
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mu', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: -1},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'muji', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 0},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mine', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 1},
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 1}, 
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido2', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: 1}, 
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido3', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 0}, 
  {animal: 'hamster', name: 'gerry', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0}, 
  {animal: 't-rex', name: 'dino', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: 0},
  {animal: 't-rex', name: 'sauro', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0},
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 's', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0}, 
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 'sss', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: -1}, 
];

const grouped = d3.groups(
  data,
  d => d.animal,
  d => d.status
).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let obj = {};
  curr[1].forEach(item => obj[item[0]] = item[1]);
  acc[curr[0]] = obj;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great, but I'm still curious why `d3.group` does not work here.